# How to hold ConEmu window from exiting?

Tags: conemu

Gurus

I am using using ConEmu command line to run a shell script in ConEmu. However ConEmu always exits after the script completes. Is there any way to make ConEmu work like "mintty -h always" which keeps the Window open?

ConEMU CLI:

ConEMU.exe /cmd C:\mybin\sh.exe my_script.sh

I wish it holds window like:

mintty.exe -h always -e C:\mybin\bash.exe my_script.sh

Thanks

Comment: You must at least show your command line!

Comment: Hi, Maximus. I've added the CLI. I just want to know how to set ConEmu to never close its window after the script finishes when started from ConEmu CLI. Mitty does it by -h always parameter.

Comment: I just solved the problm by adding "sleep 365d" to my bash script. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following syntax

```
ConEmu.exe /cmd C:\mybin\sh.exe my_script.sh -cur_console:c
```